# How do I pass a filename from one class and open (and use) its scanner in a different class? I keep getting a FileNotFoundException Result too large

Tags: java, file, class, parameter-passing

I have been working at this for about 20 hours to resolve this issue and I have come to the conclusion that I need to ask you fine people for help! I'm very new to Java and am just learning to use other classes in addition to main. I am supposed to

1. Get the customer name via user keyboard input in the main class.
2. Next, I am supposed to use the customer name to open its file in
   the `Customer` class which uses a scanner to get their name,
   address, initial acct balance and the name of their corresponding
   transaction file.
3. Now, in the `Transaction` class I am supposed
   to call in the transactionFileName (a String) as a parameter for the
   (`Transaction` class) Constructor which is used to open the Scanner
   for the customer's transactionFile.
4. Finally, I need to Load the
   transactions from the transactionFile in a method (with no
   parameters and a void return type). I keep getting a
   `FileNotFoundException` "Result too large runtime error" when I call
   `aCustomer.LoadTransaction()` in main.

The error tells me it is occurring at the `LoadTransaction()` line in the Transaction class... Here is the error:

```
run:
Enter the customer's LAST name you wish to look up: 
Tolliver
TOLLIVER.txt
5369.0
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (Result too large)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at jslab10.Transaction.LoadTransaction(Transaction.java:23)
    at jslab10.JSLAB10.main(JSLAB10.java:31)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Here is the code for `Main`, `Customer`, and the `Transaction` classes. Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated!

This is the code for the `Main` class in package Lab10JS:

```
package jslab10;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JSLAB10 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Transaction aTransaction;
    Customer aCustomer;
    String aCustomerFileName;    

    aCustomerFileName = GetFileName();

    aCustomer = new Customer(aCustomerFileName);
    aTransaction = new Transaction(); 

    System.out.println(aCustomer.GetBalance());
    String transactionFileName = aCustomer.GetTransactionFileName();
    aTransaction = new Transaction(transactionFileName);
    aTransaction.LoadTransaction();
    System.out.println(aTransaction.GetDate());

    }

    public static String GetFileName() {
        String aCustomerFileName;
        String custInput;
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the customer's LAST name you "
                + "wish to look up: ");
        custInput = kbd.nextLine();
        aCustomerFileName = custInput.toUpperCase() + ".txt"; 
        System.out.println(aCustomerFileName);
        return aCustomerFileName;
    }
}
```

This is the code for `Customer` class in Lab10JS package:

```
package jslab10;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String cityStateZip;
    private double balance;
    public static String transactionFileName;
    private String customerFileName;

    public Customer(String aCustomerFileName) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner inFileSC = new Scanner(new File(aCustomerFileName))) {

            name = inFileSC.nextLine();
            streetAddress = inFileSC.nextLine();
            cityStateZip = inFileSC.nextLine();
            balance  = Double.parseDouble(inFileSC.nextLine());
            inFileSC.nextLine();
            transactionFileName = inFileSC.nextLine();
            inFileSC.nextLine();
            inFileSC.close();
        }

        }


    public Customer() throws IOException {

    }

    public String GetTransactionFileName() {

        return transactionFileName;
    }

    public double GetBalance() {

        return balance;
    }
    /*

    private void UpdateBalance(Transaction aTransaction) {

        aTransaction.GetAmount();
        aTransaction.GetTransactionCode();

            while(aTransaction.GetTransactionCode() == 'C' || 
                  aTransaction.GetTransactionCode() == 'W' || 
                  aTransaction.GetTransactionCode() == 'T') {

            }
    }
   */ 
}
```

Here is the code for the `Transaction` class in package Lab10JS:

```
package jslab10;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Transaction {
   private String date;
   private String description;
   private double amount;
   private char transactionCode;
   private Scanner transactionFile; 


   public Transaction() {

   }

   public Transaction(String transactionFileName) throws IOException  {

       transactionFile = new Scanner(new File(transactionFileName));
   }

   public void LoadTransaction() {

        date = transactionFile.nextLine();
       description = transactionFile.nextLine();      
       amount = Double.parseDouble(transactionFile.nextLine());
       transactionFile.nextLine();
       transactionCode = transactionFile.nextLine().charAt(0); 

   }

   public String GetDate() {
      return date;
   }

   public String GetDescription() {
       return description;
   }

   public double GetAmount(){
       return amount;
   }

   public char GetTransactionCode() {
       return transactionCode;
   }

   public boolean TestMoreTransactions() {
       boolean result = false; 
       while(transactionFile.hasNext()) { 
        result = true;
       }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger, or add traces in the code, to know what the file name passed to Transaction.LoadTransaction() is. Also, respect the Java conventions: methods start with lowercase letters, variables should be declared when they're initialized, and not at the top of the method.

Comment: Thanks I did get it working finally! My professor for some reason has us define local variables at the top of the method separately from their initialization and he has us do uppercase for starting each word in the method names... I have no idea why! I have noticed from looking up different examples that he doesn't use the correct convention but the one lab I tried to name and define the correct way I got points taken off! :-)